# How to trigger directive once again after response from the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that displays the logo of the selected component object.

```
<div avatar component-id="3" 
      component-object="Modio.selectedFacility" 
      image-url="Modio.selectedFacility.logo_url" 
      bind="true" 
      style="display: inline-block" 
      wrapper-style="{'display': 'inline-block' }" 
      allow-change-photo="true" 
      size="50" 
      change-photo="modioModal.showTeamProfileModal"
      label="Profile">
</div>
```

When the user selects an object from the dropdown list, the method `setselectedFacility` is called from the service. In this method I call another method `getFacilityLogoUrl` that sends a request to the server to get the logo and as long as there is no response, a directive is called and set default image. When I get the response the update of logo does not occur.
Directive seems doesn't know that something happened.

```
this.setSelectedFacility = function(facility) {
  this.selectedFacility = facility;

  if (this.selectedFacility) {
    this.getFacilityLogoUrl(this.selectedFacility.id).then(function(url) {
      _this.selectedFacility.logo_url = url;
    }, modioException.errorFn);
  }

  //Save to local storage
  localStorageService.set('selected-facility', this.selectedFacility);
};
```

How can I say to a directive to update an old value.

Watcher in my directive:

```
if (scope.bind) {
    scope.$watch('componentObject', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue) {
            render();
        }
    });
} else {
    render();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain because you haven't posted the code for your `selectedFacility` watcher, but the problem could be that you are using a ***shallow*** watcher, but you need a ***deep*** watcher, because you are watching object properties.

Try using the third argument to the `$watch` function.  For example:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedFacility', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, true);
```

By default, `$scope.$watch()` will only check for value changes, where the value for primitives is their value, and the value for objects is their reference.  Therefore, default watches will only trigger when the object being watched is reassigned.

For objects and arrays you can use a deep watcher, as above, or `$scope.$watchCollection`, which will watch for reference changes one level deep.

Another solution is to use immutable objects, so that all changes to an object require creation of a new object (and therefore a reference change.)  This works very well with AngularJS and Angular's dirty-checking change-detection strategy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added part of the code with my watcher. When I use `$scope.$watchCollection` everyrhing seems to be working, but when I use third argument, I get this error - **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Comment: That's probably because you have circular references in your watched object, `selectedFacility`.  

`$scope.$watch('selectedFacility', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, true);` is true deep checking, using recursion.  

Recursion + circular reference = infinite loop; $watchCollection only checks the references of the first children.